# How long does a python3 mysql connection remain active?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I have a python3 script that uses a global $CONN variable as a MySQL connection.
But MySQL **connection breaks automatically** sometimes. Is there any time limit for MySQL connection in python3?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the connection times as follow:

```
con.query('SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=28800')
con.query('SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=28800')
con.query('SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=28800')
```

The numbers are in seconds, so 28800 seconds = 8 hours.

If you want to see the currently configured times, execute this query on the database:

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';`

Comment: setting `connect_timeout` to 8 hours seems a bit odd, is it not? (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout)

Comment: Agreed, it was just to showcase that it can be set to a large number.